# How do I remove an item from a stl vector with a certain value?

Tags: c++, stl

I was looking at the API documentation for stl vector, and noticed there was no method on the vector class that allowed the removal of an element with a certain value. This seems like a common operation, and it seems odd that there's no built in way to do this.

Comment: I know I've mentioned this several times before but Scott Meyer's book [Effective STL](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-STL-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0201749629/ref=sr_11_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1220372978&sr=11-1) covers these gotchas in a clear way.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385229/c-erase-vector-element-by-value-rather-than-by-position

Comment: This might be an interesting reading to you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Answer (score 191, accepted):

`std::remove` does not actually erase elements from the container: it overwrites the elements that should not be removed at the beginning of the container, and returns the iterator pointing to the next element after them. This iterator can be passed to `container_type::erase` to do the actual removal of the extra elements that are now at the end of the container:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// .. put in some values ..
int int_to_remove = n;
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), int_to_remove), vec.end());
```

Comment: Does this all-in-one-statement form depend on the order in which the compiler evaluates the arguments, or is `vec.end()` guaranteed to be the same on either side of the call to `std::remove`? It looks to me in reading other parts of the web like this is safe, but it should be stated clearly.

Comment: It's fine. The result of `vec.end()` doesn't need to be the same; it just needs to be correct (which it is).

Comment: `vec.end()` does need to be the same, but that's OK because `std::remove` doesn't change it. If it did change it (and invalidate the old value) then there would be a problem: order of evaluation of parameters is unspecified and therefore you wouldn't know whether the second `vec.end()` is still valid by the time it's used. The reason it's the same is simple, `std::remove` doesn't change the size of the container, it just moves the contents around.

Comment: I've found this question important, since I have the same problem. But, my visual studio takes `std::remove` with only one argument; that is `const char *_Filename`. What method do I need to call?

Comment: That is the version of `remove` that deletes a file. You need to include `<algorithm>` in order to access the version of `remove` that deals with containers.

Comment: For the solution with std::remove to work, one needs to have #include <algorithm> otherwise there would be error: error: cannot convert 'std::basic_string<char>::iterator …' to 'const char* for argument '1' …' on my Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Certainly! That was outside the scope of the question, though.

Comment: how to remove at specific index (not value)?

Comment: vec.erase(index_to_erase)?

Comment: How do you detect the number of elements erased?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle - I think you could insert code between the `remove` and `erase`, something like: `const size_t num_removed = vec.size() - (it_returned_by_remove - vec.begin());`

Comment: I was in doubt about what would happen if `remove` wouldn't find any element, we would end up with `vec.erase(vec.end(),vec.end()`. Then looking at the documentation of `erase`, which says elements in the interval `[a,b)` are deleted, I thought than the element pointed by the first argument  would be definitely deleted, being `[` inclusive. What I had not considered is that the interval `[a,a)` is empty, despite the `[`

Comment: @Antonio, you are laboring under a misunderstanding. `[a,b)` means "all the elements starting with `a` up to - but not including - `b`". The range `[a,a)` is contains no elements.

Comment: @MarshallClow I already repented :)

Comment: For future ref) The description of how `std::remove` works was incorrect, so I edited it - `std::remove` doesn't "move", but rather "overwrites" the not-to-be-removed elements at the beginning of the container. (P.S. Now I see that the original answer was okay because it didn't explain it, but the editing by another user was wrong.)

Answer (score 81):

If you want to remove ***an*** item, the following will be a bit more efficient.

```
std::vector<int> v;


auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);
if(it != v.end())
    v.erase(it);
```

or you may avoid overhead of moving the items if the order does not matter to you:

```
std::vector<int> v;

auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 5);

if (it != v.end()) {
  using std::swap;

  // swap the one to be removed with the last element
  // and remove the item at the end of the container
  // to prevent moving all items after '5' by one
  swap(*it, v.back());
  v.pop_back();
}
```

Which is what Jim's method of `std::vector::erase` + `std::remove` does under the hood.

Comment: Note this will not remove duplicates of the item if they exist, whereas the std::remove_if approach does.

Answer (score 16):

Use the global method std::remove with the begin and end iterator, and then use std::vector.erase to actually remove the elements.

Documentation links
std::remove http://www.cppreference.com/cppalgorithm/remove.html
std::vector.erase http://www.cppreference.com/cppvector/erase.html

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);

//Vector should contain the elements 1, 2

//Find new end iterator
std::vector<int>::iterator newEnd = std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);

//Erase the "removed" elements.
v.erase(newEnd, v.end());

//Vector should now only contain 2
```

Thanks to Jim Buck for pointing out my error.

Comment: This has the ability to prevent movement of other elements on erasure of an element in the middle of the vector therefore this is faster. It moves them to the end of the vector first then you can just discard from the end of the vector.

Answer (score 15):

From **c++20**:

A non-member function introduced `std::erase`, which takes the vector and value to be removed as inputs.

ex:

```
std::vector<int> v = {90,80,70,60,50};
std::erase(v,50);
```

Comment: Not only that, it's overloaded for each specific container!

Comment: ... and takes advantage of container-specific properties, like `map::erase`!

Answer (score 5):

See also [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to be able to use a predicate...

Here's the example from the link above:

```
vector<int> V;
V.push_back(1);
V.push_back(4);
V.push_back(2);
V.push_back(8);
V.push_back(5);
V.push_back(7);

copy(V.begin(), V.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    // The output is "1 4 2 8 5 7"

vector<int>::iterator new_end = 
    remove_if(V.begin(), V.end(), 
              compose1(bind2nd(equal_to<int>(), 0),
                       bind2nd(modulus<int>(), 2)));
V.erase(new_end, V.end()); [1]

copy(V.begin(), V.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
    // The output is "1 5 7".
```

Comment: Please add more detail to this post. As it stands, a majority of its content comes from a link, and would be lost if the link ever breaks.

Comment: what about the fact bind2nd is -(deprecated in C++11) 
(removed in C++17)

Answer (score 5):

If you have an unsorted vector, then you can simply swap with the last vector element then `resize()`.

With an ordered container, you'll be best off with ‍`std::vector::erase()`.  Note that there is a `std::remove()` defined in `<algorithm>`, but that doesn't actually do the erasing.  (Read the documentation carefully).

Answer (score 5):

The other answers cover how to do this well, but I thought I'd also point out that it's not really odd that this isn't in the vector API: it's inefficient, linear search through the vector for the value, followed by a bunch of copying to remove it.

If you're doing this operation intensively, it can be worth considering std::set instead for this reason.

Answer (score 4):

*

> C++ community has heard your request :)

*

**C++ 20** provides an easy way of doing it now. 
It gets as simple as :

```
#include <vector>
...
vector<int> cnt{5, 0, 2, 8, 0, 7};
std::erase(cnt, 0);
```

You should check out [std::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) and [std::erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2).

Not only will it remove all elements of the value (here '0'), it will do it in ***O(n)*** time complexity. Which is the very best you can get.

If your compiler does not support C++ 20, you should use [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom):

```
#include <algorithm>
...
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0), vec.end());
```

Answer (score 3):

A shorter solution (which doesn't force you to repeat the vector name 4 times) would be to use Boost:

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm_ext/erase.hpp>

// ...

boost::remove_erase(vec, int_to_remove);
```

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/new/remove_erase.html

Answer (score 0):

Two ways are there by which you can use to erase an item particularly. 
lets take a vector

```
std :: vector < int > v;
v.push_back(10);
v.push_back(20);
v.push_back(30);
v.push_back(40);
v.push_back(40);
v.push_back(50);
```

**1) Non efficient way :** Although it seems to be quite efficient but it's not because erase function delets the elements and shifts all the elements towards left by 1. 
**so its complexity will be O(n^2)**

```
std :: vector < int > :: iterator itr = v.begin();
int value = 40;
while ( itr != v.end() )
{
   if(*itr == value)
   { 
      v.erase(itr);
   }
   else
       ++itr;
}
```

**2) Efficient way ( RECOMMENDED )** : It is also known as ***ERASE - REMOVE idioms*** .

- std::remove transforms the given range into a range with all the elements that compare not equal to given element shifted to the start of the container.
- So, actually don't remove the matched elements.
  It just shifted the non matched to starting and gives an iterator to new valid end.
  It just requires O(n) complexity.

output of the remove algorithm is :

```
10 20 30 50 40 50
```

as return type of remove is iterator to the new end of that range.

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  ForwardIterator remove (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& val);
```

Now use vector’s erase function to delete elements from the new end to old end of the vector. It requires O(1) time.

```
v.erase ( std :: remove (v.begin() , v.end() , element ) , v.end () );
```

**so this method work in O(n)**

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the [erase remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom), for `vector` one could use `resize` and `remove` and use iterator distance computation:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
// .. put in some values ..
int int_to_remove = n;
vec.resize(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), int_to_remove) - vec.begin());
```

Tested [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a54995654e909f79).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do it without any extra includes:

```
vector<IComponent*> myComponents; //assume it has items in it already.
void RemoveComponent(IComponent* componentToRemove)
{
    IComponent* juggler;

    if (componentToRemove != NULL)
    {
        for (int currComponentIndex = 0; currComponentIndex < myComponents.size(); currComponentIndex++)
        {
            if (componentToRemove == myComponents[currComponentIndex])
            {
                //Since we don't care about order, swap with the last element, then delete it.
                juggler = myComponents[currComponentIndex];
                myComponents[currComponentIndex] = myComponents[myComponents.size() - 1];
                myComponents[myComponents.size() - 1] = juggler;

                //Remove it from memory and let the vector know too.
                myComponents.pop_back();
                delete juggler;
            }
        }
    }
}
```