# removing elements by value in C++ - does the preferred idiom really consist of a double negative?

Tags: c++, stl, erase, idioms

I came across this answer to the question of removing elements by value in C++:

[C++ Erase vector element by value rather than by position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385229/c-erase-vector-element-by-value-rather-than-by-position)

Basically:

```
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), valueToRemove), vec.end());
```

The answer makes sense, but isn't this bad style? The logic is consists of a double negative... is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Where do you see a double negative?

Comment: Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom Suggestion: get a copy of Scott Meyer's *Effective STL*

Comment: What is a "double negative"? Do you mean a general/logical double negative or is this some software-design term I don't know. In the latter case what does it mean? And in the former case, strange question!

Comment: see below - it was a misconception on my part. feel free to remove the question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting an element from a collection consists of two steps:

- Moving down all subsequent elements to fill in the holes created by matches
- Marking the new end

With the C++ standard library, these are two separate functions, `remove` and `erase`, respectively.

One could certainly imagine an `erase_if` type of function which would be easier to use, but evidently the current code is considered good enough.  Of course you can write your own `remove_if`.

Comment: I see, I think I actually misinterpreted the answer. Takes a while to understand all these C++ idioms. I like the wikipedia entry too : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom

Answer (score 4):

This isn't bad and in fact an efficient way of removing elements from a vector based on a condition in **linear time**. Watch this video from 35th minute. [STL explanation for the Erase and Remove Idiom](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-2-of-n)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that there are different types of containers: Contiguous vs node-based, and sequential vs associative.

Node-based containers allow efficient erase/insert. Sequential containers organize elements by insertion order (i.e. position), while associative containers arrange them by (key) value.

All current associative containers (map/set/unordered) are node-based, and with them you can erase elements directly, and you should use the element-wise member `erase` function directly. Lists are node-based sequence containers, so you can erase individual elements efficiently, but *finding* an element by value takes linear time, which is why lists offer a member `remove` function. Only sequence containers (vector and deque) have no easy way to erase elements by value, and that's where the free `remove` algorithm comes in, which first *rearranges* the sequence to then allow the container's member `erase` to perform an efficient erasure at the end of the container.

Unlike the many generic aspects of the standard library which work without any knowledge of the underlying container, the copy/erase idiom is one of those things which require a bit of detail knowledge about the differences between the containers.