# std::remove causes compile error

Tags: c++, linux, vector, std, stl-algorithm

I am trying to use answers for [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385229/c-erase-vector-element-by-value-rather-than-by-position) and get strange error -

> /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:162: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* with _Iterator = User*, _Container = std::vector, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = User& == __val’

I'm using Linux(Ubuntu 64-bit) and maybe that is a problem. 
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: 
code where I use remove():

```
myVec.erase(std::remove(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), vecMember), myVec.end());
```

Comment: Could you post a small code sample that reproduces the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

std::remove calls `operator==`, you need to overload it for your `User type`:

assume you compare User by name:

```
bool operator==(const User& lhs, const User& rhs)
{
   return lhs.name == rhs.name;
}
```

If you read carefully, compiler message tells you what exactly is missing.

Alternatively use [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) with lambda if you use C++11

```
myVec.erase(std::remove(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), 
            [](const User& u){ return u.name == "name"; }), vec.end());
```

Comment: Alternatively use `remove_if`.

Comment: Don't forget to use `-std=c++0x` if you want to use lambdas (OP is using g++ 4.6).