# How to erase vector element by pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have this:

```
vector<Object*> myVec;
```

and adding my objects to it like this:

```
Object *obj1 = new Object;
myVec.push_back(obj1);
```

Let's assume that I have 100 objects in this way and pointers going as *obj1, *obj2 ... *obj100.
And now I want to remove let's say, obj37, from the vector. I wish I could do that just like pushing it:

```
myVec.remove_back(obj37);
```

It would be awesome if there was a function like "remove_back" but there is not I think.
I hope you got the point and please help me about that.

By the way, just look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385229/c-erase-vector-element-by-value-rather-than-by-position), in accepted answer, there is remove algorithm works by value:

```
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 8), vec.end());
```

I gave it a shot that with pointer even I didn't believe that would work and surprise; it didn't:

```
myVec.erase(std::remove(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), *obj37), vec.end());
```

Yeah, I know that I've just bullshit but that's for you got the point. Somewhere there should be a simple solution like this and I just want that.

Comment: The simple solution is to not manually manage your memory. If you really need pointers, use smart pointers. As you have a collection of pointers, though, if you want to compare the dereferenced pointers rather than the pointers themselves, you'll need to provide your own comparator to `std::remove_if`.

Comment: If you are sure that you need functionality that vector provides to you in your program then I would suggest you to change a data structure from std::vector<Object*> to std::map<int, Object*>.

Comment: @chris Yeah, I was using boost shared_ptrs but I've removed them back after reading a nice article. Besides, I just wanna do everything by myself 'cause I'm new at C++ and OOP and believe that this will bring on me better. I will look for `std::remove_if` Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're almost there: Search the element *by value*:

```
myVec.erase(std::remove(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), obj37), myvec.end());
//                                                  ^^^^^
```

Alternatively, if you know that the element is in position 36 (0-based), you can erase it directly:

```
myvec.erase(myvec.begin() + 36);
```

Or, in modern C++:

```
myvec.erase(next(begin(myvec), + 36));
```

Also note that `std::remove` searches the entire vector, so if you know that there is only one element, you can use `find` instead to stop as soon as you find the value:

```
{
    auto it = std::find(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), obj37);
    if (it != myVec.end()) { myVec.erase(it); }
}
```

Comment: Oh come ooonn :) I feel so stupid just right now :) How didn't I try that without *? And I can't erase it by position because obj37 was just an assumption I couldn't know the position in my thing. `myVec.erase(std::remove(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), obj37), myvec.end());` working like a charm. Thank you so much.

Comment: For those who cannot get this compiled, don't forget to `#include <algorithm>`

Answer (score 2):

`std::remove()` "removes" the values matching the last argument. That is, you can remove your pointer like this:

```
myVec.erase(std::remove(myVec.begin(), myVec.end(), ptr), myVec.end());
```

If there is just one element matching it may be easier to use `std::find()` instead of `std::remove()`. If you actually want to match the pointed to value you'd use the `_if` version of the algorithm with a suitable predicate. Of course, removing the pointer won't release any memory.

Answer (score -1):

If you use C++11 you can put smart pointers into your vector. Than you can use the erase-method to remove the object and automaticly the smart pointer handles the delete pointer stuff.

```cpp
vector<std::shared_ptr<Object>> myVec;
```

The shared_ptr has a reference rounter inside. If the object is not referenced by any variable it will be delete automaticly.