# vector erase-remove idiom compile error

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have the following `removeOneParam(Parameter* param)` code which is from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385229/c-erase-vector-element-by-value-rather-than-by-position):

```
class A
    {
        private:
          std::vector<Parameter*> params;
        public:
          void removeOneParam(Parameter* param)
          {
            params.erase(std::remove(params.begin(), params.end(), param), params.end());
          }
}
```

But I get the following compile error:

*`error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<Parameter*>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Parameter**, std::vector<Parameter*> >}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int remove(const char*)`*

How can I use that answer to my case?

Comment: You forgot to `#include <algorithm>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler is picking up the version of `std::remove` in the `cstdio` header, not the one you want. You're probably missing `#include <algorithm>`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that header `algorithm` is not included. Try to

```
#include <algorithm>
```

and then all should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include at the top of your program `include <algorithm>`

That should make the errors disappear.