# Remove pointer element from std::vector using the erase-remove idiom

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

Taken from [C++ Erase vector element by value rather than by position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385229/c-erase-vector-element-by-value-rather-than-by-position)

The answer states that if you have a vector of int's you can use the erase-remove idiom to remove an element by it's value like so:

```
vec.erase(std::remove(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 8), vec.end());
```

Where 8 is an element in the list.

My question is, using this same technique is it possible to remove a pointer element with a pointer as a value like so:

```
std::vector<T*> m_list;

T* value;
m_list.erase(std::remove(m_list.begin(), m_list.end(), value), m_list.end());
```

Given that "value" is an element in the list.

Comment: Yes, of course. It's not the `int`s that's important, it's that they're equality-comparable against the value you pass in. And even that's not important, since you could use `remove_if` instead.

Comment: This may cause a memory leak if the pointer were dynamiclly alocated.  Look at using [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) instead of raw pointers

Comment: If the vector owns allocated pointers, erase is a memory leak.

Comment: @NathanOliver In my case the use of smart pointers is not an option. Is there a way to remove it and make sure it doesn't leak?

Comment: If by `remove it` you mean erase then AFAIK no.  Why can't you use smart pointers?  If you can't use C++11 boost has them.

Comment: @Belfer4 The remove itself, does not produce a memory leak (if the vector owns allocated pointers)