# Compare two vectors<customObject> with common variables to delete C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have two vectors

```
vector<TestResults> testResults;
vector<Students> students;
```

both have `studentId`. After I've deleted a student from the student vector I want to delete his testresults from `testResults`.

I want to delete every record on `testResults` with `studentId == 0`.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't found anything related to my question. Maybe it sounds like a pretty simple question. to delete a student I did students.erase(students.begin() + choice); but I can't do that here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385229/c-erase-vector-element-by-value-rather-than-by-position didn't help me at all. Everything is with an int, not an object.

Comment: you may want to give us more information about the structures of testResults and Students

Comment: The top answer on the linked question addresses exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Maybe, I don't understand any of it. The answer below was directed more to my case I feel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<TestResults>::iterator it = testResults.begin();
for (; it != testResults.end();) {
    if (it->studendId == 0) {
        it = testResults.erase(it);
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great :)