# Deleting elements in a vector of pointers to vectors of objects

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector set up as follows:

```
vector< vector<myClass>* > vec;
```

I am having trouble deleting elements from vec however, I have dynamically allocated all elements in vec, and am trying to delete the ith element as follows:

```
vector<myClass> *victim = vec[i];
delete victim;
victim = 0;
```

However this does not seem to be correctly removing them from vec. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

try using vector::erase to remove it from the vector. The delete will free the memory only but the vector will keep the pointer unless you removed it.

have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3385251/249120

Comment: That did the trick, can't believe I forgot about that. Thank you

Comment: @Kaze : you can check this answer as the accepted answer if it is the answer.