# How to erase all elements from a vector except for the largest in a specific range?

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I have the following vector:

The vector is a vector of pairs, and we are comparing based on the first element.

```
[(1,0),(0,1),(3,2),(6,3),(2,4),(4,5),(7,6),(5,7)]
```

I want to erase all elements in a specific range except the largest.

For example, if the range was $l = 2$ and $r = 5$, then the output:

```
[(1,0),(0,1),(6,3),(7,6),(5,7)]
```

Now if we do this again to the output array for $l = 1$, $r = 4$, then the output:

```
[(1,0),(7,6)]
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385229/c-erase-vector-element-by-value-rather-than-by-position) which I thought would be useful here, but I don't know how to make it work for pairs.

Here is my attempt:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector< pair<int,int> > vector_of_pairs(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        vector_of_pairs[i] = make_pair(input, i);
    }

    int l, r;
    cin >> l >> r;

    int max_in_range = vector_of_pairs[l].first;

    for (int i = l+1; i <= r; i++) {
        if (vector_of_pairs[i].first > max_in_range) {
            max_in_range = vector_of_pairs[i].first;
        }
    }

    for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) {
        if (vector_of_pairs[i].first != max_in_range) {
            vector_of_pairs.erase(vector_of_pairs.begin() + i);
        }
    }

    printf("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < vector_of_pairs.size(); i++) {
        printf("(%d,%d)", vector_of_pairs[i].first, vector_of_pairs[i].second);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

For the following input:

```
8              
1 0 5 6 2 3 7 4 
1 3
```

This is the output:

```
[(1,0)(5,2)(6,3)(3,5)(7,6)(4,7)]
```

But it should be

```
[(1,0)(6,3)(3,5)(7,6)(4,7)]
```

Also, for certain inputs I get seg faults so how can I safe guard against that?

Comment: Please post / hardcode the input in in the program itself.  No need to keep typing in the input at the keyboard.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @PaulMcKenzie? Do you mean I should include input/output sample in the code?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie std::vector< std::pair< int , int > > input { std::make_pair( 1 , 0 ) ,
              std::make_pair( 0 , 1 ) ,
              std::make_pair( 3 , 2 ) ,
              std::make_pair( 6 , 3 ) ,
              std::make_pair( 2 , 4 ) ,
              std::make_pair( 4 , 5 ) ,
              std::make_pair( 7 , 6 ) ,
              std::make_pair( 5 , 7 ) };

Comment: @user6005857: Like [this](https://ideone.com/Q9hxu6).

Comment: When you erase, future `begin() + i` would be not what you expect.

Comment: @user6005857 *how can I safe guard against that* -- If you find yourself writing `for` loops that erases something from a container based on a criteria, you're going about this the wrong way.  There is the `std::remove / remove_if`, followed by `erase()`.  Tailor these calls to your particular situation, then you don't need to write any (faulty) loops.

Comment: dont you think for input l=1, r=3 output should be [(1,0)(6,3)(2,4)(3,5)(7,6)(4,7)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probabaly you want this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    vector< pair<int,int> > vector_of_pairs(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        vector_of_pairs[i] = make_pair(input, i);
    }

    int l, r;
    cin >> l >> r;

    int max_in_range = vector_of_pairs[l].first;

    for (int i = l+1; i <= r; i++) {
        if (vector_of_pairs[i].first > max_in_range) {
            max_in_range = vector_of_pairs[i].first;
        }
    }
    int p=l;
    for (int i = l; i <= r;i++ ) {
        if (vector_of_pairs[p].first != max_in_range) {
            vector_of_pairs.erase(vector_of_pairs.begin()+p);
        }
        else p++; 
    }

    printf("[");
    for(int i = 0; i < vector_of_pairs.size(); i++) {
        printf("(%d,%d)", vector_of_pairs[i].first, vector_of_pairs[i].second);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}
```

Getting correct output :

```
[(1,0)(6,3)(2,4)(3,5)(7,6)(4,7)]
```

**Explanation:** When you delete an item in vector, items present after the deleted element get decreased their index by 1. Hence in the ith loop from l to r you shouldn't delete vec.begin()+i element, instead delete vec.begin()+l item until you find largest element, and delete vec.begin()+l+1 element after you find largest element.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You might replace `done` by a counter in case there are multiple max.

Comment: Too `C`-ish.  Erasing from a container depending on a certain criteria, can be done more succinctly using various algorithms, mainly `std::remove_if` and `erase`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, all numbers are unique, there cannot be multiple max. However, I am getting wrong output with this answer.

Comment: can you try now?

Comment: dont you think for input l=1, r=3 output should be [(1,0)(6,3)(2,4)(3,5)(7,6)(4,7)]

Answer (score 6):

[Erase remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) at the rescue:

```
auto begin = v.begin() + l;
auto end = v.begin() + r + 1;
auto max_value = *std::max_element(begin, end);
v.erase(std::remove_if(begin, end,
                       [&](const auto& p) {return p.first != max_value.first; }),
        end);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/tXHmZJ)

Comment: -.- you beat me to it by a second

Comment: This is an amazing solution! But I am getting a compiler error on `[&]` and warning on `auto`. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: @user6005857 Are you using a `C++ 11` compliant compiler?

Comment: might be worth noting that this solution won't work for all containers unless they changed how list iterators work

Comment: @deW1: OP uses `std::vector`. `v.begin() + x` might indeed may be replaced by `std::next(v.begin(), x)`.

Comment: ofc, wasn't supposed to be criticism, just a note for anyone who'd like to adapt this to non vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a stable algorithm you can simply sort the vector, get iterator for `l` in `begin - end`, get iterator for `r` in `l - end` and then remove all but the very last element between both found iterators.

```
#include <algorithm>
template<class V, class T>
void remove_range_but_max(V& vop, T const& l, T const& r)
{
    std::sort(vop.begin(), vop.end());
    auto lo = std::lower_bound(vop.begin(), vop.end(), l);
    auto hi = std::lower_bound(lo, vop.end(), r);
    if(hi != lo) --hi;
    vop.erase(lo, hi);
}
```

can be used like:

```
std::vector< std::pair< int , int > > input { 
    std::make_pair( 1 , 0 ) , std::make_pair( 0 , 1 ) , 
    std::make_pair( 3 , 2 ) , std::make_pair( 6 , 3 ) , 
    std::make_pair( 2 , 4 ) , std::make_pair( 4 , 5 ) , 
    std::make_pair( 7 , 6 ) , std::make_pair( 5 , 7 ) };
/* remove all pairs in range [(2,0), (6,0)) */
remove_range_but_max(input, std::make_pair(2,0), std::make_pair(6,0));
for(auto&& p : input) std::cout << p.first << ", " << p.second << "\n";
```

Prints:

```
0, 1
1, 0
5, 7
6, 3
7, 6
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick and sleazy way:

```
std::sort(vector_of_pairs.begin(), vector_of_pairs.end());
vector_of_pairs.resize(1);
```

**Just be sure to supply sort with the appropriate function to make the largest element get pushed to the first of the list.**

Let me spell it out for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool i_said_to_do_this(const pair<int, int> &lhs, const pair<int, int> &rhs) {
  return lhs.first > rhs.first;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    int pairs[][2] = {{1,0},{0,1},{3,2},{6,3},{2,4},{4,5},{7,6},{5,7}}; 
    vector< pair<int,int> > vector_of_pairs(8);

    for (int i{0}; i < 8; i++) {
      vector_of_pairs[i] = make_pair(pairs[i][0], pairs[i][1]);
    }

    std::sort(vector_of_pairs.begin(), vector_of_pairs.end(), i_said_to_do_this);
    vector_of_pairs.erase(vector_of_pairs.begin() + 1, vector_of_pairs.end());

    cout << "(" << vector_of_pairs[0].first << ", " << vector_of_pairs[0].second << ")" << endl;
}
```

Comment: This gives the output [(0,1)] with all input.

Comment: @user6005857 My answer was correct, you appear to have not noticed the part I indicated after the code sample. By default, you will get the smallest value, and you have to change the sort to get the results that you want.

Comment: @Aumnayan: OP wants to keep element of a range and discard the other alement of the range. and the range may be less that the whole vector.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks I missed that and updated my answer.Just replace begin() and end() calls with the iterator range you're looking to operate on.

Comment: And you also have to handle `tie` then.