# Return element at index in a vector

Tags: c++

How can I remove an element at a specified index in a vector, and then return that element?
Is there a method for that?

Comment: Does it have to be in that order? You can use `operator[]` or `at()`, followed by `erase()` if not.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912/how-do-i-remove-an-item-from-a-stl-vector-with-a-certain-value

Comment: @Beginner, Not really. It isn't searching by value, so using `remove` is a bit pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) can remove an element at a specified index, but does not return that element.

You can just do:

```
aboutToBeErased = myVector.at(index);
myVector.erase(myVector.begin() + index);
```

Be careful though, vectors are not good at removing elements that aren't at the end of the vector. This can be a costly operation for large vectors.

Comment: `vector:erase` doesn't take an `int` as argument

Comment: for the erase line, I got error "IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call"

Comment: should be `myVector.erase(std::next(myVector.begin(), index));`

Answer (score 3):

1. To get the element, you can use **[`std::vector::at()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/at/)**

   ```
   value = mVector.at(n);
   ```
2. To erase, **[`std::vector::erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/)**
   The following would erase item no. `n+1` and resize your vector.

   ```
   mVector.erase (mVector.begin()+n);
   ```

Erase shifts all elements and hence, indexes if you do erase an element in the middle.

Comment: The asker wants the element too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function, written in C++11, that will get the nth element from a vector and erase it reasonably efficiently:

```
template<typename Vector>
typename Vector::value_type getAndErase( Vector& vec, size_t index )
{
  Assert( index < vec.size() );
  typename Vector::value_type retval = std::move(vec[index]);
  vec.erase( vec.begin()+index );
  return retval;
}
```