# How do I remove an element from a vector based on a condition?

Tags: c++

I have a vector which I use for an observer pattern to register the name and pointer: a registration list.
I want to unregister an observers from the vector pair. 
I am not sure how to proceed, I tried this but does not compile at all.

```
vector < pair<string , Observer* > > destination;

void subject::unregisterObservers(LogObserver* obsIfP)
    {
        vector <pair<string, LogObserverIf*> > ::iterator it;
        for(it = observers.begin(); it != observers.end(); it++)
        {
            if((*it).second == obsIfP)
            {
                remove(observers.begin(), observers.end(), (*it).first);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I remove elements from the vector based on one of the values inside a pair element?

Comment: Any reason for not using an std::map?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912/how-do-i-remove-an-item-from-a-stl-vector-with-a-certain-value

Comment: Are you going to tell us what the compiler error is? And what is `observers`?

Comment: std::remove value argument is that of the vector's element, in this case pair<string, LogObserverIf*>, which a string can't be implicitly converted to. That's why it wont compile.

Comment: I did not want to have an order or comparator implemented when using map, as orders will be sorted. The registration list is better compatible as vector.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `vector::erase()` instead.

```
    for(it = observers.begin(); it != observers.end(); it++)
    {
        if(it->second == obsIfP)
        {
            observers.erase(it);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is dangerous as it will invalidate the iterators!

Comment: As long as the loop is broken once erasure happen, it's not a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your current code.

std::remove will find and *move* elements equal to the given value to the end of the container. It then returns the iterator pointing to the end of the non-removed range in the vector. To have them completely removed would require vector.erase with the iterator returned from the remove algorithm.

**The erase-remove idiom:**

```
v.erase( remove( begin(v), end(v), value ), end(v) )
```

Note, your code gives a string as value and will not compile, since elements in the vector are pair< string, Observer* > and the algorithm can't compare between the two.

**Erasing while iterating over the same range is dangerous**, since you may invalidate the iterators of the first loop.

**Using algorithms with predicates:**

Depending on the size of the vector, it may just be simpler (and even faster) to generate a new vector.

```
typedef pair<string, Observer*> RegPair;
vector<RegPair> new_observers;
new_observers.reserve( observers.size() ); // To avoid resizing during copy.

remove_copy_if( begin(observers), end(obervers), std::back_inserter(new_observers),
    [obsIfP]( const RegPair& p ) -> bool
        { return p.second == obsIfP; } );

observers = std::move(new_observers);

// --- OR THIS

observers.erase( remove_if( begin(observers), end(observers),
        [obsIfP]( const RegPair& p ) -> bool
            { return p.second == obsIfP; } ),
        end(observers) );
```

Removing an element in the middle of a vector will cause all the following elements to be moved back one index, which is essentially just a copy anyway. If more than one element has the observer pointer, your initial code would have to move these elements more than once, while this suggestion always has a worst case of O(N), where the elementary operation is a copy of the pair element. If better performance than O(N) is required, you'll have to arrange your observers with std::map< string, Observer* > or perhaps boost::bimap which lets you use both pair values as keys.

The difference between remove_if and copy_remove_if would be the preserving of order. remove_if may swap elements and place them elsewhere in order to get the removed element to the end-range. The copy_remove_if will simply not copy it over to the new container, so order is preserved.

If you're not using c++11, the lambda wont work and you'll have to hand code the loop yourself.