# C++ vector::erase complains about overload resolution & deleted operator '=='

Tags: c++, vector, stl, stdvector

I am on `C++` using `std::vector` to store a list of class objects using `vector::push_back`.

My add function accepts the base class type so that the same method can be used across.

```
Add(MyBaseClass object) {
  my_vector.push_back(object)
}
```

I have remove function to remove it by per item added

```
Remove(MyBaseClass object) {
  my_vector.erase(std::remove(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), object), my_vector.end());
}
```

The add works fine but my **Remove method gives following error:**

```
overload resolution selected deleted operator '=='
            if (!(*__i == __value_))
              ~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~
```

I picked up the vector::erase code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912/how-do-i-remove-an-item-from-a-stl-vector-with-a-certain-value). **What is wrong with my way of erasing an item? Are there any other preferable ways to erase by item?**

Comment: Does `MyBaseClass` have a `operator ==`?

Comment: nope. Do I need to have one defined ? shouldn't the default provided work ?

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting that to work with subclasses of `MyBaseClass`. It doesn't; read about "object slicing".

Comment: @SegmentationFault There is no default provided `operator==` for classes.

Comment: There is no default provided one.  If you want it you need to define it.

Comment: ok...ok. I will define an `==` operator. thanks

Comment: what if I am adding `std::functions` ? for example to implement callbacks, I want to have a list callbacks & remove each at will

Answer (score 3):

The *Multipass guarantee* of the `ForwardIterator` requirement for `remove` to work on `std::vector` specifies that `MyBaseClass` *must* implement `operator==`.

Your class doesn't appear to implement this, and compilation therefore fails.

Comment: ok. let me try to define an `==` operator in my base class & check

Comment: what if I am adding `std::functions` ? for example to implement callbacks, I want to have a list callbacks & remove each at will