# Selection sort - loop stops too early

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to write selection sort. Everything works but my algorithm is not looping through whole vector `_item` leaving my `v_sorted` too short. Elements are sorted properly.

sort.hpp

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> selection_sort(std::vector<T>);
```

sort.cpp

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> selection_sort(std::vector<T> _item) {
    std::vector<T> v_sorted;
    for(int i = 0; i < _item.size(); ++i) {
        T smallest = _item[0];
        for(auto const& j : _item) {
            if(j < smallest) {
                smallest = j;
            }
        }
        v_sorted.push_back(smallest);

        auto it = std::find(_item.begin(), _item.end(), smallest);
        if (it != _item.end()) {
            // to prevent moving all of items in vector
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/15998752
            std::swap(*it, _item.back());
            _item.pop_back();
        }
    }
    return v_sorted;
}

template std::vector<int> selection_sort(std::vector<int> _item);
```

sort_tests.hpp

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(selection_sort_int)
{
    std::vector<int> v_unsorted = {3, 1, 2, 7, 6};
    std::vector<int> v_sorted = {1, 2, 3, 6, 7};
    auto v_test = exl::selection_sort(v_unsorted);
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL_COLLECTIONS(v_sorted.begin(), v_sorted.end(), 
                                  v_test.begin(), v_test.end());
}
```

This test is failing with `Collections size mismatch: 5 != 3`. Any test is failing with size mismatch. Loop is stopping (in this case) after three iterations. Thanks in advance for any clues.

Comment: Consider the effect of `pop_back()`.

Comment: If you're unsure, add `std::cout << "i = " << i << ", _item.size() = " << _item.size() << std::endl;` at the beginning of your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simultaneous effects of the for loop's `++i` and the `_item.pop_back()` has the effect of incrementing twice, when you only wanted to increment once.

Change the for loop to a while loop:

```
while(!_item.empty())
```

### [Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MixDNLM6Z9UcbCLf)

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are re-implementing `std::min_element`, and you if you use it, you don't need to find the element again, you also don't want to change the size of `_item` whilst looping over it's `size()`.

You can also sort in place, as follows:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> selection_sort(std::vector<T> _item) {
    for(auto it = _item.begin(); it != _item.end(); ++it) {
        auto smallest = std::min_element(it, _item.end());
        std::iter_swap(it, smallest);
    }
    return _item;
}
```

Comment: @SirGuy Oops, good catch. And I've now arrived at approximately [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap)