# How to resolve the problem when vector pop_back the rbegin iterator became invalidated?

Tags: c++17

I want to remove a certain value from a vector using the following code.

```
void removeValue(int n, vector<int>& v)
{
    for (auto it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); ++it) {
        if (*it == n) {
            std::swap_iter(it, v.rbegin());
            v.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is if the last element in the vector equal to the value, after pop back, the it will be invalidated. Is there some way to fix this error?

For now, I rewrite this function by using index to avoid iterator invalidation.

```
void removeValue(int n, std::vector<int>& v)
{
    for (size_t i = v.size(); i > 0; --i)
    {
        if (v[i - 1] == n)
        {
            std::swap(v[i - 1], v.back());
            v.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes; don't pop_back right away, but wait until you scanned all the array. Then resize by the total amount. (Of course you don't swap with the last element each time.)

Comment: I would just use erase-remove and be done with it. [How do I remove an item from a stl vector with a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912/how-do-i-remove-an-item-from-a-stl-vector-with-a-certain-value) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom

Comment: @RetiredNinja This method looks good, but maybe it's less efficient because the algorithm will keep the elements' order

Comment: Depends on the input. E.g. for the sequence `[a x x x ... x b]`, where `x` is the element to be removed, your algorithm will make `O(n)` swaps while erase-remove would make one swap (to move `b` to right after `a`).

Answer (score 0):

In general, do not modify your container inside a scoped auto-incremented for-loops while you are dealing with magical iterators.

Here is a safe code snippet removing items from your container while iterating on it:

```
void removeValue(int n, std::vector<int>& v)
{
    auto itr = v.begin();
    while(itr != v.end())
    {
        if(*itr == n)
        {
            itr = v.erase(itr);
            continue;
        }
        ++itr;
    }
}
```